# Why is python requests getting different results than Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write a Python script that logs into website for me and downloads my messages. I'm using the the "requests" library and succesfully able to log in with a session

The website uses js/Ajax to download the actual messages client side after the messages page has been loaded, and uses pagination to achive an infinite list of messages effect.

The messages page url is in the form of `https://website.com/messages`. and that page contains an Ajax call that retrives the messsages like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/messages?mailbox=' + mailbox + optional params
    }).done(function(data) {
        urlLazyLoading = data.next_page_url;
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
             //from this point on, data for each message can be 
             //accessed using the v object as such: 
             //v.sender, v.date, v.last_message, etc
             //and the <ul> element is populated with '<li>'s
```

But when I try to access the same url in python (after I've loggedin) as such:

```
session.get('https://website.com/messages?mailbox=inbox')
```

instead of getting a json response with the messages data, I get the same/original messages page.

the only parameter passed to ajax in the code above is `url`, so by defult it should be just making a simple GET request, which is what I'm doing.

Is it possible that maybe somewhere else in the code ajax is being set up to default to POST or have some other non-default settings?

or is the server somehow detecting that one request is coming from ajax and the other from sessions? maybe using `user-agent`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Ajax sends a header value by default:

{'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

I added that in and viola

```
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    r = s.get("https://website.com/messages?mailbox=inbox",headers=headers)
```